# How to see real time updates of file system at terminal?

Tags: filesystem, terminator, realtime

I am studying git and how it works with file system. I installed application called terminator, which allows me to open multiple terminals. I want to run git commands at the left terminal and want to see at right terminal real time updates of file system. How it is possible?

[image]

Comment: By "real time updates" do you mean modifications in existing files, creation/deletion of files, both or something else?

Comment: yes, creation and deletion of files, I would prefer something that looks like a tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `watch` command for that. 
In the default setting it executes the trailing command every 2 seconds. The time can be specified with `-n`.

To use it to monitor your filesystem you may either use `ls -1` (if you want to see only one directory) or `find` (if you also want to watch subdirectories) as the command.

To check for changes in /tmp and all of its subdirectories in (near)real time execute `watch -n 0.1 find /tmp`. An interval of 0.1 seconds is the fastest, `watch` can go and should be sufficient for any human. And I assume you are human, aren't you?

Comment: You give me a clue, but I found tree command, which prints file system snapshot like a tree.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: There is just showing tree of that watch folder. but dont show me any changes on file system of that directory. I run this command `watch -n 0.1 find  /home` for my home folder 
`